# File Upload Using React JS and Node JS not returns undefined or empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, request, upload

I am trying to upload files to my NodeJS backend using a react JS frontend. I am appending the files to a formData object but the files are not appearing on the backend.

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState([]);

function handleFileInputChange(event) {
  setSelectedFile(event.target.files);
}

function handleFileUpload(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  console.log(1);
  formData.append("files", selectedFile[0]);

  axios.post(`http://localhost:5300/api/Uploads/uploadFiles/${accountid}`, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(selectedFile[0]);
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
};
```

I tried to console log the files but nothing is appearing and it's causing errors

At first, I want using a for loop to append several files to the formData object but then I only tried one file. Both scenarios gave me an error and failed.
I tried sending the files using Postman. It worked and the files appeared normally on the backend. But when I try to send them through the react frontend they do not appear.
Below is a simplified version of the backend to understand how the code is working

```
uploadSeveral: async function (req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id;
    var UploadFile = multer({ 
        storage: Upload.files.storage(id), 
        fileFilter: Upload.files.allowedFile }).
        array('files',10);
    UploadFile(req, res, async function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
        }
        else {
            try{
            const folderId = await createFolder(id)
            const files = req.files;
            console.log(req.files);
            console.log(files[0].path);
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Files uploaded successfully' });
            }catch(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I console.log the req.files I get an empty array with an error message because there is no files[0].path.

Comment: And what does `console.log(req.files)` logs?